# php -v shows PHP 7.2.24

Tags: php, xampp

I downloaded & installed [xampp-linux-x64-7.4.6-0-installer.run](https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/7.4.6/xampp-linux-x64-7.4.6-0-installer.run) on my VM using terminal. Everything went right except PHP version.

The terminal output

```
php -v

PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.4 (cli) (built: Apr  8 2020 15:45:57) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
   with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

but php info shows version 7.4.6

[image]

is there any way to upgrade php version ??

Comment: You need to change your `$PATH` to point to the upgraded version.

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade the installed php to 7.4.6? or downgrade XAMPP's php to 7.2.24?

Comment: need to upgrade ...

Comment: PHP_CLI !== (PHP_FPM || PHP_MOD_APACHE)

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use this comand to set the default php version:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```